# after jquery hide ajax request is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

only first time ajax call working when i hide that div and the next time ajax request is not going.

a)when i hit the signup button ajax request send and the details will shown

b)when i click hide button ,it hides everything in that div

c)when i again click signup another ajax request and show the div..//but this step is not working

```
 <html>
  <div id="cont">
  <div id="cont_lista_sx">
    <br /> <br /> <br />
  <div>  <input type="button" value="signup"  onclick="changeval();"/>
  </div>
  <br /> <br /> 

  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="hide" onclick="onhide();"/>


  <script language="javascript">

    function changeval(context)
    {

    var typeval="sdsf";
      var url="sdfsdf";
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'.../registration',
        data:'&typeval='+typeval+'&url='+url,
        success:function(data) { 
          $( "#cont_lista_sx" ).html( data );

        }

      });

    }
     function onhide()
    {
     $( "#cont_lista_sx" ).hide();
    }
  </script>
</zcms:escape>
```

i have searched a lot but i didnt get answer,
the script is working and also the the code is reaching the url but data is not displyed

Comment: Is this 'htp://sscs/registration' correct?  Do you ever run `.show()`?

Comment: yes its not the correct url in my code i use the context, 'htp://sscs/registration  just for example

Comment: it working fine at first time and when i hide it and again try to signup it is not displaying

Comment: .show worked thank you very much after  $( "#cont_lista_sx" ).html( data ); i added  $( "#cont_lista_sx" ).show(); and it worked

Comment: thank you kelly j i wasted a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

It should be
`data:'?typeval='+typeval+'&url='+url,`
not
`data:'&typeval='+typeval+'&url='+url,`
and also check your function

```
onclick="changeval();"
```

And

```
function changeval(context){}
```

what about context?